# Google Scripts mysterious execution time and logger behavior

Tags: logging, spreadsheet, execution

This is my first time working with google scripts and I don't have any prior javascript experience. There came a point a couple days ago where my script stopped updating the log and as far as I could tell, wasn't running. 
It instead was showing one of two messages up top: Either "Running Function ClassPlans..."  or  "Preparing for Execution...".

At first I changed the Logger.log() statements to make the logger display different things but I noticed that the log wasn't being updated. I thought it was my internet connection (even though my other tabs were completely fine) so I decided to stop and then continue later. I came back to it today and am on different internet yet the problem persists.

```
function ClassPlans(period, prep, curren) {

    Logger.clear();
    var spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var calendar = spread.getActiveSheet();
    var planned = calendar.getCurrentCell();
    var row = planned.getRow();
    var column = planned.getColumn();
    Logger.log("1");

    var everything = calendar.getRange(1,column,row-1).getValues();


    var prep_name = everything[1];
    var period_name = everything[0];
    var last = everything.length - 1;
    while (everything[last] == ''){
        last = last -1;
    }
    var previous = everything[last];
    var prep_info = spread.getSheetByName(prep_name);
    var curriculum = prep_info.getRange("G7:G148").getValues();
    var skew = 0;
    if (period_name == "Period 2"){skew = skew + 4;}
    if (period_name == "Period 3"){skew = skew + 8;}
    if (period_name == "Period 4"){skew = skew + 12;}
    if (period_name == "Period 5"){skew = skew + 16;}
    if (period_name == "Period 6"){skew = skew + 20;}
    var period_info = prep_info.getRange(7,skew + 10,293,1);
    var count = 0;
    Logger.log("last");
    while (curriculum[count] != previous){
        Logger.log("hI");
        count = count + 1;
    }
    return previous;
}
```

enter code here

Even more strange: the logger is updated itself but is not showing things that sync up with the Logger.log() calls I have in the current version of the function... They do sync up with previous versions of the function I've written. I am confused about the logger and also about why the function is exceeding the maximum execution time because from what I can tell, my while loops are formatted properly and are in no way creating infinite loops. I also minimized my calls to the spreadsheet and the sheets. The only thing that I could think is slowing it down is that maybe my calls to the sheet are very large? Am I missing something? Or do I have some extra stuff that is not necessary? 
[Log picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssZes.png)

Comment: Please, add the code as a code, not as an image

Comment: sorry about that, is what I have now acceptable?